# The spy who was killed

Tags: password

A spy tries to infiltrate into a Spanish base. In order to do so, he pinpointed a spot where he could listen the people outside of the gate who were asked to answer a short question. These questions were:

> **Guard:** 14.
>   **First outsider answer:**  7.
>
> **Guard:** 18.
>   **Second outsider answer:** 9.

Once the spy heard this, he realised that he always needed to give the half of the number as a response. So he went to the base,

> **Guard:** 6.
>   **Spy answer:** 3.

The spy was immediately killed.
Why this happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the standard "count the letters in the word" puzzle, but in Spanish. 14 is "catorce" (7 letters) and 18 is "dieciocho" (nine letters). So he should have answered 4, because "seis" (Spanish for 6) has four letters.

Comment: Haha, good. I didn't think it was going to be solved that fast.